# Find cause of ant failure

Tags: java, ant

I have some ant files that one imports the other. Specifically `build.xml` imports a `project_default.xml`. When I try to do a build I get following error:

> Buildfile: C:\myproject\build.xml     [taskdef] Could not load
>   definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties. It
>   could not be found.
>
> BUILD FAILED   C:\myproject\build.xml:14: The following error occurred
>   while executing this line:   C:\myproject\project_default.xml:17:
>   Problem: failed to create task or type if   Cause: The name is
>   undefined.   Action: Check the spelling.   Action: Check that any
>   custom tasks/types have been declared.   Action: Check that any
>   / declarations have taken place.

Line 17 that is reported is the following:

```
<if>   
<contains string="${env.PROJECT_SELECTION}" substring="env.PROJECT_SELECTION" />
```

I also added the following in the `build.xml`:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">  
  <classpath>  
    <pathelement location="D:\UserData\ant-contrib-0.6-bin\lib\ant-contrib-0.6.jar"/>  
  </classpath>  
</taskdef>
```

But got the same error. Any idea of what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

with ant version > 1.6 you should use "net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" instead of "net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"

so change the taskdef to this:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">  
  <classpath>  
    <pathelement location="D:\UserData\ant-contrib-0.6-bin\lib\ant-contrib-0.6.jar"/>  
  </classpath>  
</taskdef>
```

cheers,

Comment: Copy-pasted your code and still get the same error.`Could not load definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties.`

Comment: hi, where in your build.xml file are you doing the taskdef? is the jar file really located at "D:\UserData\ant-contrib-0.6-bin\lib\ant-contrib-0.6.jar"? rather than defining it explicitly, you could also move it to the lib directory of your ant installation... this way you don't need the <classpath>...</classpath>

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is that you have the ant-contrib jar path corrext. Run ant with `-verbose` to get more info about what it's doing and what tasks it's trying to load from where.

Where did you add the taskdef? If you're using the `<if>` task outside a target then you need the taskdef before it, also outside a target. If you're using it inside a target then the taskdef can be (textually) after the call as long as it is either outside a target or in a target that runs before the `<if>` in dependency order.

Comment: This is not my ant files and I see that the `<if>` is not part of a `taskdef` or `target`